# IEnumerable Casting 2 IEnumerables into one class

Tags: .net, xml, linq-to-xml, ienumerable

I have 2 IEnumerables

```
IEnumerable<float> Distance
IEnumerable<XElement> Point
```

which i want to convert into

```
IEnumerable<Subsection> subsection
```

where the Class is

```
class Subsection
{
    public float Distance
    public XElement Point
}
```

But i have no idea how to do this, i have tried some variations of casting none of which has worked because they dont seem to accept multiple lists as inputs.

The Distance and Point variables are read from a xml document where the structure for these two points is similar to:

```
<PLI>
    <Distance>5</Distance>
    <Point>23 22</Point>
    <Distance>7</Distance>
    <Point>21 72</Point>
    <Distance>9</Distance>
    <Point>13 32</Point>
</PLI>
```

I wasn't sure how to read them out simply as the subsection type but if anyone could suggest how to do that, it would bypass my need to convert it as i will no longer have them as IEnumerables of distance and point but as the structure.

Please note I cannot modify the XML

Thanks

**EDIT:** The XML has other elements as well as the ones mentioned within the PLI Tag e.g.

```
<PLI>
    <OtherElement1>element1value</OtherElement1>
    <OtherElement2>element2value</OtherElement2>
    <Distance>5</Distance>
    <Point>23 22</Point>
    <Distance>7</Distance>
    <Point>21 72</Point>
    <Distance>9</Distance>
    <Point>13 32</Point>
</PLI>
```

Comment: Updated my post to account for other elements. This only affected the non-LINQ approach. The `Zip` approach was unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull this off with LINQ with the help of the [Enumerable.Zip method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx), provided your XML is balanced (an even number of elements to pair up distances and points).

```
var query = xml.Elements("Distance")
               .Zip(xml.Elements("Point"),
                    (d, p) => new Subsection
                    {
                        Distance = float.Parse(d.Value),
                        Point = p
                    });
```

Alternately, you could loop through the elements and build up the `Subsection` items. This can be done as follows, although it assumes your XML document is balanced and in the expected format.

```
var query = xml.Elements()
               .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Distance"
                           || e.Name.LocalName == "Point");
var list = new List<Subsection>();
int count = 0;
Subsection s = null;
foreach (var element in query)
{
    if (count % 2 == 0)
        s = new Subsection { Distance = float.Parse(element.Value) };
    else
    {
        s.Point = element;
        list.Add(s);
    }

    count++;
}
```

Note that in both snippets the `xml` variable is an `XElement`. For an `XDocument` add the `Root` property, as in `xml.Root.Elements(...)`.

Comment: Updated the 2nd approach to filter `Distance` and `Point` elements and work with those only. Again, you need to be sure they're balanced. If you're unsure then an upfront `.Count()` check on both collection of elements, checking that their sum is even (modulus 2 == 0) should suffice.

Comment: Thanks the zip function was exactly what i was looking for, have never seen it before

Answer (score 1):

This is not referentially transparent and completely inadvisable, but if you have your heart set on LINQ, this is the best idea I have for now for this particular problem. This way your order is guaranteed to be the same.

```
public class SubSection
{
    public float Distance;
    public XElement Point;

    public SubSection(XElement distance, XElement point)
    {
        Distance = float.Parse(distance.Value);
        Point = point;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c = XDocument.Parse(@"<PLI>
<Distance>5</Distance>
<Point>23 22</Point>
<Distance>7</Distance>
<Point>21 72</Point>
<Distance>9</Distance>
<Point>13 32</Point>
</PLI>");

        var sup = new List<SubSection>();
        c.Elements().Elements().Aggregate<XElement,XElement>(null, (a, d) =>
            {
                if (a == null)
                    return d;
                sup.Add(new SubSection(a, d));
                return null;
            });
        foreach (var entry in sup)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry.Distance);
        }

    }
}
```